# Visual Studio 2015 windows disappear when trying to debug

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2015

hoping somebody has run into this issue and knows a fix as it's driving me up the wall...

I mainly write web applications at my place of work and we've recently got our upgrade to Visual Studio 2015 Professional (Version 14.0.23107.0).
Since my first fresh install (and subsequent reinstalls) whenever I attach to a process to debug all my code windows disappear. If I click on the "Windows" menu bar item then I can still see those that have disappeared, but when I try to open them they refuse to appear.

If a breakpoint was get hit on one of those "missing" files then I would get the standard "browse to find source" window you often get when using 3rd party libraries.
What I have to do at the moment is place all my break points, close all my windows and then attach to my w3p.exe process. It's pretty annoying and I was wondering if anyone else had encountered this?

For reference, I'm using IIS 7.5.7600 on Windows 7 Professional on SP1.

Below is an example image of what I see when, on a brand new ASP.NET 4.6 project, when I place a breakpoint on the `Index` method in `HomeController`.  If I click "Browse and find HomeController.cs" absolutely nothing happens.
[image]

Does anyone know what I can do to alleviate this issue?

EDIT:  Also happens when debugging straight from Visual Studio using IISExpress

Comment: My guess is that the process that you debug does not have any symbols. The normal worflow is to open a project in Visual Studio and then start debugging the project from within Visual Studio. Using the DEBUG build will give you a nice debugging experience. But you attach to an already running process. Does that process have symbols (PDB files) and are the source files referenced in these symbols available to Visual Studio?

Comment: I've just tried running the bare bones project straight from Visual Studio using IIS Express and it's the same outcome unfortunately.  I imagine there's something weird with my installation but a wipe and re-install didn't solve it.

Comment: I have the same problem using version 14.0.25123.00 Update 2. In my case this is not a web project, but a desktop application.